# Selenium and node-replay

Tags: node.js, angularjs, selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Hi I am having trouble connecting node-replay to selenium (where I am running my protractor tests for my angularjs app).

My tests run with grunt:
    grunt protractor

And they work fine.

But now I have installed node-replay and added the following lines to my test file:

```
var Replay = require('replay');
Replay.localhost('127.0.0.1:9000/');
```

And all of my tests fail when I try to run node-replay in record mode

```
 REPLAY=record grunt protractor
```

even though I'm running my tests locally on '127.0.0.1:9000/' do I have to add anything about node-replay to my protractor config file?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 127.0.0.1 is treated the same as localhost meaning node-replay will just proxy all requests without recording them. (similar to running replay=CHEAT)

https://github.com/assaf/node-replay/commit/87da96f01bfbaa23ee49c0156ba6d369e7b50cd6